# Does it matter where I put a trap{} in my PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I have some PowerShell scripts with a load of initialization steps, at the end of which I put a `trap{}` statement, intending to catch all unhandled errors *from that point onwards*.

Unexpectedly I realized that when I goofed in my initialization logic the `trap{}` was being called even though the error happened before the `trap{}` was defined.

A simple example:

```
Write-Host "Hello"
Write-Out "World"  # Incorrect cmdlet name causes an error

trap{
  Write-Warning "Ouch"
  return $null
}
```

Gives:

```
Hello
WARNING: Ouch
```

Clearly it seems that it doesn't matter that the `trap{}` is defined after the buggy line of code, but can someone explain why this works anyway?

Comment: Traps are an outdated PowerShell feature. You're better off using try catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [about_Trap](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847742.aspx):

> A script or command can have multiple Trap statements. Trap statements
>   can appear anywhere in the script or command.

You might consider using [`try`/`catch`/`finally`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847793.aspx) if you want more control over which code you want to catch exceptions for.

Comment: Thanks. I use `try{}catch{}` a lot, but use `$ErrorActionPreference="Stop"` and have a `trap{}` as a safety net, which helps discover unexpected problems.

Comment: And now I want to know what happens if I put more than one `trap{}` in the same scope...

Comment: @CharlieJoynt also covered in the link, it uses the most specific one (you can trap specific exceptions like you can with `catch`).